# Vagrant, VirtualBox built-in or no?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Trying to get set up with Vagrant but getting the error:

```
The "VBoxManage" command or one of its dependencies could not be found. 
Please verify VirtualBox is properly installed. You can verify everything 
is okay by running "VBoxManage --version" and verifying that the VirtualBox 
version is outputted.
```

Just confused because the Vagrant documentation states:

"The getting started guide will use Vagrant with VirtualBox, since it is free, available on every major platform, and **built-in to Vagrant.**"

Don't want to install VirtualBox separately if its supposed to be included when I installed Vagrant. Running OSX 10.8 if it's relevant, guessing I just need to install VirtualBox? If that's the case, what do they mean in the documentation when they say it's "built-in"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Installing VirtualBox is required if you plan on using VirtualBox with Vagrant. I'm guessing they meant that the VirtualBox integration is built-in?

Recently, they've abstracted out the VirtualBox specific code and are working on allowing for multiple providers. I believe VMWare is now [supported](http://www.vagrantup.com/vmware) in addition to VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

I had this message but my problem was different. I use Vmware_fusion as the provider. Vagrant was not able to detect what provider I am using.It assumed that I am using VirtualBox. Had this issue fixed by calling vagrant up provider flag. Here is the full command

```
   vagrant up --provider vmware_fusion
```